# When an element's id is not used, should it should be removed?

Tags: html, design-patterns

When an element's id is not used, should it should be removed?

Example:

```
< div id="neverImplementedId" class="row">
```

Comment: Hi @Sparta -- Unfortunately, I don't know how to help you.  Can you provide some code that you have tried out to implement this and where you're running into problems?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear on the question, @Doug, the question is whether there is any convention to remove the id

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity; if I'm understanding correctly, he's asking about best practices for when an id is unused.

Comment: Yes, thank you @RyanZim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can leave it in. An `id` can always be used as an anchor by a visitor to your page, so you never can say that it's 'unused'.